# While using AWS Fargate with Aws batch, for every job does a different compute environment is spawned?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-fargate, aws-batch

Whenever a job runs in a job queue in AWS batch, does a different compute environment is spawned for every job or is it same?

I'm just starting with AWS batch with fargate so wanted to clear some things out like:

1. Can I override my parameters I've set in job definition while submitting them in job queues?
2. aws job max limit if job not is consuming max memory do I get charged for maximum memory?
3. for every job different compute environment gets spawned?
4. Can I limit jobs to 3 even there are 10 jobs in queue?